# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://metastore.example.com/metastore in Google Dataproc Serverless

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

I am trying to run a Spark job using Google Cloud Dataproc Serverless. This jobs runs fine when I run it using a normal dataproc Spark cluster. It uses a Hive metastore stored in a mysql db. When I run the job using Dataproc batches, I get the below error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:mysql://metastore.example.com/metastore, username = test123. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://metastore.example.com/metastore
```

I have tried including the mysql connector jar in my pom and adding the below config

```
spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Both of these didn't work. Kindly help.

Comment: Hi @Piyush Shrivastava, Have you checked these documenations, [link1](https://www.javatpoint.com/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbc) and [link2](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/issues/1064) ? Let me know if this helps you resolving the issue or not.

Comment: What is the full command? Did you include something like `--properties hive:hive.metastore.uris=thrift://<hostname>:9083`?

Answer (score 0):

Dataproc Serverless Spark does not come with pre-installed MySQL driver - you need to include MySQL driver as a dependency to the Dataproc Serverless Spark Batch if your job needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I needed to add this jar in the Docker image used to run the job. I created a custom image, uploaded it to artifact registry and passed it in my spark submit command to make it work.